# Pinterest invite system with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, devise, invite, invitation

What is the best practice with **Devise 2.1** to build a simple invite system just like Pinterest?

In other words, I would like to allow new users to sign-up with an invitation form. Then, I would like that:

1. First, Devise send a "*Thanks for Joining the Fuu Waiting List*" email.
2. To finish, maybe with a cron-task every 3 hours, Devise send a "*You've Been Invited to Join Fuu*" email.

I'm using Devise 2.1 with confirmable module.  I think `devise_invitable` gem is not useful in my case, because invited user should not be able to invite new user.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a kindoff similar question before maybe it is of any use to you:

[rails beta request signup with social media sharing reward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920466/rails-beta-request-signup-with-social-media-sharing-reward)

Basically what you want to do is store the email of the user in a "requests" model so you get a table where you can store the email and create a field type boolean with processed. This results in:

```
|email         |processed|
john@doe.com    true
alex@google.com false
```

Then in /lib/tasks/ create a new rake tasks that loops true all your requests and process them in batches. This is the rough Idea but it should get you started.

Comment: I see... But I mean, is there a clean way to do so? In my app, pending user (asking for an invit) are just like normal user, with a `confirmed_at` field to `nil`. If there's a clean howto step-by-step, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Rough idea to get you started:
What you basically want is store wich users are signed up true your invitation system.
Stackoverflow is not for complete workouts its to get you in the right direction ;) this is to complex to totally write out.

Routes:

```
    get '/signup/:code' => "devise/registrations#new"
```

Controller:

```
params[:code]

unless params[:code] 
   .. check if the code is correct
   .. render your form here
else
  .. you need an invitation code to join our site
end
```

Model

```
on_create :set_processed
def set_processed
  .. set processed to true
end
```